# merge two arrays to print the data in html

Tags: php

I need to merge two arrays to print the data in html 
or print data directly but with my code it print duplicated data.

This is arrays come from database :

```
Array
(
    [Course name] => English 4A
    [Grade out of weight exam] => 47.25
)
Array
(
    [Course name] => Humanities 4A
    [Grade out of weight exam] => 45.00
)

Array
(
    [FullName] => Adam Sherif Wahba Ibrahim Botros
    [Course name] => English 4A
    [Grade name] => 2nd Term
    [Grade] => 74.25
    [MAX] => 100.00
    [Percentage] => 74.25
    [Grade out of weight] => 247.50
    [gi.aggregationcoef*100] => 333.33300
)


Array
(
    [FullName] => Adam Sherif Wahba Ibrahim Botros
    [Course name] => Humanities 4A
    [Grade name] => 2nd Term
    [Grade] => 73.20
    [MAX] => 100.00
    [Percentage] => 73.20
    [Grade out of weight] => 244.00
    [gi.aggregationcoef*100] => 333.33000
)
```

this is my html code and php

```
<table border='1'>        
  <tr class="tr">    
    <th class="th"> subject </th>
    <th class="th"> student's Work out of </th>
    <th class="th"> exam out of  </th>
    <th class="th">  total out of </th>
    <th class="th">  Grade </th>
  </tr>
    <?php
  $sql = "SELECT 
    c.fullname AS'Course name'  ,
    ROUND( ROUND(gg.finalgrade / gg.rawgrademax * 100 ,2) *(gi.aggregationcoef*100)/100,2) AS  'Grade out of weight exam'
    FROM 
    mdl_course AS c 
    JOIN mdl_grade_items AS gi ON gi.courseid = c.id
    JOIN mdl_grade_grades AS gg ON gg.itemid = gi.id
    JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = gg.userid
    WHERE gi.courseid = c.id AND gi.itemname in ('2nd Term EXAM')
     AND gi.itemtype = 'Category' and u.id = '5'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
     extract($row);

    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($row) ;
    echo '</pre>';
    }
    ///////////////// second SQL Get 2nd term 

    $sql2 = "SELECT 
    CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS FullName ,  c.fullname AS'Course name'  , gi.itemname AS 'Grade name',
    ROUND(gg.finalgrade,2) AS Grade
    ,ROUND(gg.rawgrademax,2) AS MAX, ROUND(gg.finalgrade / gg.rawgrademax * 100 ,2) AS Percentage
    ,ROUND( ROUND(gg.finalgrade / gg.rawgrademax * 100 ,2) *(gi.aggregationcoef*100)/100,2) AS  'Grade out of weight'
    ,gi.aggregationcoef*100

    FROM 
    mdl_course AS c 
    JOIN mdl_grade_items AS gi ON gi.courseid = c.id
    JOIN mdl_grade_grades AS gg ON gg.itemid = gi.id
    JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = gg.userid
    WHERE gi.courseid = c.id AND gi.itemname in ( '2nd Term')
     AND gi.itemtype = 'Category' and u.id = '5'"
     ;

     $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
      while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
    {
     extract($row2);    
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($row2) ;
    echo '</pre>';


    ?>

  <tr class="tr">

    <td class="td"><?php echo $row2["Course name"]; ?></td>
    <td class="td"><?php echo ($row2["Grade out of weight"] - $row["Grade out of weight exam"]); ?></td> 

    <td class="td"><?php echo $row["Grade out of weight exam"]; ?></td> 
    <td class="td"><?php echo $row2["Grade out of weight"]; ?></td>
    <td class="td"><?php echo $row[""]; ?></td>

    <?php 
    }
    ?>     
    <td class="td"> </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: marge => merge, tow => two, correct and update your question pls.

Comment: Please edit your question, your code is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = [];
foreach ($array2 as $key) {
    $array1[] = $key;
}
foreach ($array3 as $key) {
    $array1[] = $key;
}
var_dump($array1);
```